# UIWebView Not open a link but safari does

Tags: ios, ios7, uiwebview, safari, uiwebviewdelegate

I have tried to open a link in UIWebView it does not open and throw error.

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)" UserInfo=0x9a2b020 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://epapir.info/apotek1/1402/#/1/, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://epapir.info/apotek1/1402/#/1/}
```

and show images

[image]

Please advise.It open in safari browser in iPhone and working well there.Following is my code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

    //URL Requst Object
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //Load the request in the UIWebView.
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
   // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [activity stopAnimating];

}
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [activity stopAnimating];
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the link to Haneke?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this..

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]canOpenURL:url])
```

{
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:url];

```
        }
```

USe this in the VoewDidappear method though

Comment: i want to know what is the reason this site is not getting opened on uiwebview.

Comment: It had happened with me before it has something to do with the URL we are hitting…It turns out this thing happens incase we are making another request before a previous request has completed loading

Comment: not just hitting thr url not making any other request  for manu url it works

Answer (score -1):

Just add an NSLog in your didFailLoadWithError and check

```
 -(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
 {
 [activity stopAnimating];
  NSLog(@"ERROR : %@",error); //Get informed of the error FIRST
   }
```